# Blocked from reviewing?

Tags: discussion, new-users

I have periodically reviewed posts on CV over the past few years. In recent months anytime I click on 'review' there are never any available tasks.

Has my account been blocked from reviewing and if so how come?

Comment: I suspect that the explanation is very simple. High reputation users are sufficiently zealous here that queues disappear quickly. Compare, for example, Stack Overflow with $>120,000$ close votes in the air....

Comment: I have had the same experience :-).

Comment: It happens to us all, I'm afraid ... one thing (of many) the moderators and high-rep users here manage to be very efficient at is keeping those review queues short. Sometimes I have to wait days before I get one. That's a good thing.

Comment: Right now it's about 2am Sunday morning on the US east coast (not where I am, but probably an approximate time for the bulk of users) and there's exactly *one* item across six review queues, and it's only been there a short time (a few minutes, I'd guess). Even if I don't review it, someone else will have taken care of it before I can go get a cup of coffee.

Comment: Thanks all for your responses - has alleviated my paranoia! I do get a certain perverse satifaction from correcting bad grammar and phrasing but certainly not a pressing issue.

Comment: I can relate :) I probably got a few hundred rep points (2 at a time) just out of correcting bad grammar, spelling, punctuation, even capitalization! It was quite perversely satisfying.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you *can't* perform a review task, it will be grayed out, as at your rep level should be the case with all except the `First Posts` and `Late Answers` tasks. When I'm around, I'm one of those zealous users that's causing your problem ;) I check the review queue between practically every page navigation precisely because these tasks' queues empty so quickly – of course, in the process, I exacerbate the "problem" in which I share. My solution was to hit the next tier of privileges so I could start reviewing suggested edits too. I imagine higher-rep users will be alternately relieved and disappointed that my overzealous editing won't need reviewing anymore, nor fertilize their badge farms :) In summary, I'm afraid the only solution is to keep up with the crowd! Good luck to you (it's not easy in this crowd!), and may the fastest reviewer – *who doesn't sacrifice thoroughness and tact* – "win"!